# When to use 'is' or 'are'?

Tags: word-choice

Which statement is correct?

Alcohol, drug abuse and work equipment is a lethal mix.

or

Alcohol, drug abuse and work equipment are a lethal mix.

Comment: I don't actually thinks this is a duplicate of that question...

Answer (score 1):

Either version could be grammatically correct as a treatment of a list of nouns, but I am going to suggest the latter is preferable for the most natural meaning in this case.

> Alcohol, drug abuse and work equipment is a lethal mix.

This takes the set of components as a single group and makes it the subject.

> Alcohol, drug abuse and work equipment are a lethal mix.

This cognizes each component separately.

Here's two examples of where the group should be singular:

> Tomato juice, vodka, Worcestershire sauce, and celery is a bloody mary.
>
> A fuselage, two wings, and some engines is an airplane.

In this case, we could make the sentence clearer by substituting *is the definition of* or *makes up*. The nouns in our subject compose a clause taken to be a single thing. I think these sentences generally sound more natural if you express the term first.

---

Conversely, I take it that we should prefer to view them separately when we see distinct types of agents:

> Jim and Bob are a dangerous combination at any party.
>
> Bleach and ammonia are dangerous mixture.

In this case, I take it that we want to emphasize the components. And this is the case in your question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The second statement is correct - the plural form of the verb to be. There is more than item in the lethal mix. 
e.g.
Use of is:

```
Drug abuse is potentially lethal.
```

Use of are:

```
Alcohol and drug abuse are potentially lethal.
```

Comment: You've changed the OP's wording. Your two sentences are absolutely correct, but there's nothing wrong with using *is* with the original wording.